# include_once errors with youtube api / Zend Gdata

Tags: php, zend-gdata

I'm using Zend Framework ver 1.11.10, specifically the GDATA/YouTube functions.

My log is getting blasted with

```
include_once(Zend\Gdata\Media\Extension\VideoQuery.php) failed to open stream: No such file or directory C:\Zend\ZendServer\share\ZendFramework\library\Zend\Loader.php 148
include_once(): Failed opening "Zend\Gdata\Media\Extension\VideoQuery.php" for inclusion (include_path=".;C:\Zend\ZendServer\share\ZendFramework\library") C:\Zend\ZendServer\share\ZendFramework\library\Zend\Loader.php 148
include_once(Zend\Gdata\Media\VideoQuery.php) failed to open stream: No such file or directory C:\Zend\ZendServer\share\ZendFramework\library\Zend\Loader.php 148
include_once() Failed opening "Zend\Gdata\Media\VideoQuery.php" for inclusion (include_path=".;C:\Zend\ZendServer\share\ZendFramework\library") C:\Zend\ZendServer\share\ZendFramework\library\Zend\Loader.php 148
include_once(Zend\Gdata\YouTube\Extension\VideoQuery.php) failed to open stream: No such file or directory C:\Zend\ZendServer\share\ZendFramework\library\Zend\Loader.php 148
include_once()  Failed opening "Zend\Gdata\YouTube\Extension\VideoQuery.php" for inclusion (include_path=".;C:\Zend\ZendServer\share\ZendFramework\library") C:\Zend\ZendServer\share\ZendFramework\library\Zend\Loader.php 148
```

Stepping through the code, I get to gdata\app.php in line 1046 where its looping through all the `_registeredpackages`, the first 3 being the ones listed above until it gets to the right class Zend_Gdata_YouTube.

So my question is how can I get the above messaged to not log? Seems there would be a fail-safe to verify the file exists before it tries to include it.

*Note: I went back and reviewed my logs and these errors haven't always been there, even when using the Zend framework. I'm wondering if I caused this to happen somehow.*

Comment: Please attach a minimal code example that produces those warnings.

Comment: I'm getting the exact same thing with Zend 1.11.10

Answer (score 1):

I've solved it by calling `registerPackage('Zend_Gdata_YouTube');` on `Zend_Gdata_YouTube` instance.

```
$yt = new Zend_Gdata_YouTube();
$yt->registerPackage('Zend_Gdata_YouTube');
```

This simply `unshift` the correct package to `_registeredpackages`.

Now the following code doesn't produce errors by `Zend_Loader`:

```
$yt->newVideoQuery();
```